# remove particular order status from list in magento

Tags: magento

I am using extension

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/eitai2001/extension/1468/order-status/reviews#reviews

of magento which provide a lot of order status..but my need is limited ..so i want to remove some status from my order-status list... how can i do this..please help
Thanks!

**Edited**
 I made change in **config.xml**
If I comment any order-status ... like this

`<!--<processing_cc_settled translate="label"><label>Processing - Credit Card has been Settled</label></processing_cc_settled>-->`

but in combobox(where status shows in admin site )still *processing_cc_settled* appears at the same place where **Processing - Credit Card has been Settled** showing up before commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the same extension that I have seen installed one client's site then it should have a config.xml file included in its /etc subdirectory (**NOTE**: not the global /app/etc but somwhere in the /app/code/community/ folder). In this file you will find definitions for all the additional statuses. Just comment out the ones you don't want. You can also change the ones that you leave so that they are better suited to your needs.

**CLARIFICATION:**

Here's a piece of my config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Sales_Community>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </Mage_Sales_Community>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <sales>
            <order>
                <statuses>
                    <!--Complete Status Descriptions-->
                    <complete translate="label"><label>Dispatched</label></complete>
                    <!--Cancelled Status Descriptions-->
                    <canceled translate="label"><label>Suspended</label></canceled>
                    <!--<canceled_discontinued translate="label"><label>Suspended - No stock</label></canceled_discontinued> -->
                    <!-- /* Additional custom statuses will go here */ -->
                    <!-- Format of a status description is <name_of_status translate="label"><label>Name of Status</label?</name_of_status> -->
                </statuses>
            </order>
        </sales>
    </global>
</config>
```

Note that complete and canceled have a different label defined. There is also a canceled_discontinued status, but it is not used as the whole entry is commented out. If the entry stays on the order comments dropdown after you have commented it make sure that you have refreshed the cache...

Comment: yes I have made changes in that same config.xml file..like <processing_cc_settled translate="label"><label>Processing - Credit Card has been Settled</label></processing_cc_settled> 


if i comment it ..in combobox(where status shows) "processing_cc_settled" appears

Comment: @Richa: Please have a look at my clarification above.

Comment: I have did the same but when i commented it...in dropdown at the place of this entry, name of this entry appears like if I considered your example..
it shows "canceled_discontinued" at the place of "Suspended - No stock"

Answer (score 0):

I add/remove magento statuses in install scripts, using something like below:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

/*
Possible states:

Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CLOSED
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PAYMENT_REVIEW
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PENDING_PAYMENT
Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING         
*/

$installer->startSetup();

// Get status model
$status = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status');


// Delete some statuses
$status->setStatus('processing_cc_settled')->delete();
$status->setStatus('another_status_code_to_delete')->delete();


//Add a new status
$status->setStatus('holded_cc_error')
       ->setLabel('On Hold: CC Error')
       ->assignState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_HOLDED) 
//for example, use any available existing state from above
       ->save();

//To set an order to this status:
//$order->setData('state', "holded");
//$order->setStatus("holded_cc_error");
//$order->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```