# How to remove Magento custom order status

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I've added new order status in the Admin Panel. I need to remove it, but I can't find option like that.

Is that possible to do it without the database viewing?

Comment: Isn't there `Unassign` link on the grid?

Comment: Yes, there was, but it hasn't removed the status.

Comment: This link may be help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536630/remove-particular-order-status-from-list-in-magento

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are no way to delete the custom order statuses from Magento admin but you can delete it from Database tables

```
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_label
```

Comment: Is this all that is required for Magento 2 too?